# Can i use the :first-letter and the :hover selector together?

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have the first letter selector working, to change the color of the first letter but when hovering that area the color matches with the background so it becomes invisible. This is the part of code working

```
.nav-menu li a:first-letter {color:#b5b503;}

.nav-menu li a:first-letter {font-weight:bold;}


.nav-menu li a {


    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And this is the part where i guess i should add a .first-letter selector but cant find out how as it is already a hover selector in it

```
.nav-menu li:hover > a,
.nav-menu li a:hover {

    background-color: #b5b503;
    color: #273664;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can

Example CSS :

```
p:first-letter {
    font-size: 120%;   
}
p:hover:first-letter {
    color: white;
}
```

HTML :

```
<p>Hello world</p>
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/LRFw8/1/

For your code, you would style this in `.nav-menu li a:hover:first-letter`